# Deleting terms from universal sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I call an infinite sequence of 0's and 1's *universal* if it contains every finite sequence of 0's and 1's as a subsequence. Now suppose we delete from a universal sequence finitely or infinitely many terms in a completely arbitrary manner, with the only restriction that no two consecutive terms are ever to be deleted. Is it then true that the remaining terms will always form a universal sequence?

Answer (score 1):

When you delete only finitely many terms, the sequence is still universal. This is because, for any sequence $s$, the sequences $$s,0s,00s,\dots,0^ns,\dots$$ all appear, so $s$ appears infinitely often, so deleting finitely many terms preserves that.

If you're allowed to delete infinitely many terms, then everywhere you see $\dots010\dots$, delete the $1$. Now there won't be any subsequences containing $010$, so universality has been destroyed.

Comment: This is brilliant! So simple as so elegant! Though I am a bit disappointed with the negative result I cannot fail to recognize the beauty of your counterexample. Thank you very much.